# How to custom sort array indexes in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array or arrays which I also use in my configuration file. The file is also manually edited so I want some of the keys to have fixed position. The code reads configuration file with this array, modifies, insert keys etc and then saves it back. On save I sort the keys but now I found that it is not good enough.

Is there any way to have

- the key `'full_name'` always as the first key
- the key `'version'` as second one
- and the rest of the keys to be sorted alphabetically?

Sample of the array....

```
array (
  'skroob' => 
  array (
    'ssh' => 'skroob',
    'codebase_path' => '/srv/www/htdocs/imacs/radek/4.0.1',
    'ssh_status' => 'ok',
    'version' => '4.0.1',
    'ssh_last_access' => '2012-Feb-17 10:07:26',
    'edu_url' => 'https://testing/imacs/radek/4.0.1',
    'full_name' => 'skroob 4.0.1',
  ),
  'testing' => 
  array (
    'full_name' => 'My beautiful testing server (trunk)',
    'version' => 'trunk',
    'ssh' => 'testing',
    'codebase_path' => '/srv/www/htdocs/imacs/radek/trunk',
    'ssh_last_access' => '2012-Feb-17 10:07:26',
    'ssh_status' => 'ok',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. It sorts the array alphabetically, by key. Then it reverses the array and unsets the `full_name` and `version keys`. Then it adds those keys again, so they get placed at the end of the array. Lastly, it reverses the array again. Kinda hacky but I'm not sure there's a much better way to do what you're asking.

```
ksort($arr['skroob']);

$arr['skroob'] = array_reverse($arr['skroob']);

$version = $arr['skroob']['version'];
$full_name = $arr['skroob']['full_name'];

unset($arr['skroob']['full_name'], $arr['skroob']['version']);

$arr['skroob']['version'] = $version;
$arr['skroob']['full_name'] = $full_name;

$arr['skroob'] = array_reverse($arr['skroob']);
```

Another solution is to use uksort and write a small callback function. That would probably look a bit more professional.

Comment: Cool, there is no other solution I have one :-) Thank you.